# Как анимировать исчезание обьекта?

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

У меня есть ItemsControl, внутри него есть элементы. Есть крестик который удаляет элемент из ObservableCollection(Все на MVVM). Я смог сделать анимацию появления элементов через Grid.Loaded ивент и Doubleanimation (opacity). Но как сделать обратное? Элемент удаляется без анимации(даже с задержкой в секунду). Использую Grid.Unloaded.

```
 <ui:Card
                                        Name="BookItem"
                                        Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                                        <ui:Card.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                            From="0"
                                                            To="1.0"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Unloaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                            From="1.0"
                                                            To="0"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>


                                        </ui:Card.Triggers>
```

Comment: Фактическое удаление надо делать после того как анимация завершена. [Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564124/12888024) я накостылял когда-то похожий механизм на то что вам нужно. Кстати, почему вас совсем не заботит как другие участиники видят ваш вопрос? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHAnt.jpg

Comment: Хотя по ссылке там объект висит фиксированное время, 10 сек, а потом исчезает, наверное не совсем то.